# How to count the highest left and highest right heights?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, max

I have to write a method that counts the highest left and highest 
right heights of the current index.
Let's say we have the array {1,4,7,3,2}, so for index 1 ( height 4) - the `maxLeftHeight=1` , `maxRightHeight=7` and for index 2(height 7)  - `maxLeftHeight=4`, `maxRightHeight=3` and so on...

The first and the last indexes don't count so the array starts counting at 1 and finishes counting at `array.length-1`

I tried to write a code for this and this is what I got:

```
public String getCurrentMaxHeights(int[] height)
{
  int maxLeft = 0;
  int maxRight = 0;
  String st = "";
  for (int i = 1; i < height.length - 1; i++)
  {

    maxRight = Math.max(height[i + 1], height[height.length - 1]);
    maxLeft = Math.max(height[i - 1], height[0]);
    st += "The max left height for " + height[i] + " is " + maxLeft +
      " the max right height is " + maxRight + " \n";

  }
  return st;
}
```

**output:**

The max left height for 1 is 2 the max right height is 3 
The max left height for 1 is 2 the max right height is 4 
The max left height for 4 is 2 the max right height is 3 
The max left height for 1 is 4 the max right height is 3 
The max left height for 1 is 2 the max right height is 3 
The max left height for 2 is 2 the max right height is 3

This is wrong, how can I fix it to be right?

Comment: 'Nested _array_"?  Perhaps you meant nested **loops** instead...

Comment: Are you trying to build a nested array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `2 nested for-loops`:

- One for getting the `maxLeft`.
- One for getting the `maxRight.`

Where `i` is the current index, run from `0` to `i - 1`, calculating `maxLeft` and run from `i + 1` to `n - 1`, calculating `maxRight`.

```
public String getCurrentMaxHeights(int[] height)
{
   int maxLeft;
   int maxRight;
   String st = "";
   for (int i = 1; i < height.length - 1; i++)
   {
        // Initialize to first element.
        maxLeft = height[0]
        // Update if any are greater.
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            maxLeft = Math.max(maxLeft, height[j])
        // Initialize to element following i.
        maxRight = height[i + 1]
        // Update if any are greater.
        for (int j = i + 2; j < height.length; j++)
            maxRight = Math.max(maxRight, height[j])

        st += "The max left height for " + height[i] + " is " + maxLeft +
    " the max right height is " + maxRight + " \n";
   }
return st;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `selectedIndex` is the `index` you start from, Moreover, add check if there is values on the `left` or the `right` or not

```
  Integer[] leftValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray, 0, selectedIndex);
  Integer[] rightValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray, selectedIndex+1,numArray.length);
  List<Integer> leftList = Arrays.asList(leftValues);
  List<Integer> rightList = Arrays.asList(rightValues);
  int leftMax = 
  leftList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();
  int rightMax= 
  rightList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();
```

Another way with complete example if you want it with `int array` not `Integer`:

```
  int[] spam = new int[] { 1, 2, 3,5,4,7,1,2,9,12 };
  int[] leftValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(spam, 0, 7);
  int[] rightValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(spam, 7+1,spam.length );
  List<Integer> leftList = Arrays.stream(leftValues).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  List<Integer> rightList = Arrays.stream(rightValues).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  int leftMax = leftList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();
  int rightMax= 
         rightList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();
```